Passing in arguments to Dependency function makes it recognized as a Query Parameter
Take a look at the following Route Handler
@some_router.post("/some-route") 
async def handleRoute(something = Depends(lambda request : do_something(request, "some-argument"))):     
    return JSONResponse(content = {"msg": "Route"}, status_code = 200)

So the dependency function "do_something" takes in a request and string value. But passing it in like so makes it so that its recognized as a query parameter now even though it shouldn't. Its just an argument thats needed for the dependency function.

The "do_something" implementation
async def do_something(request: Request, value: str):
    pass
This is obviously an example code. How can I pass in the request along with the string value into the "do_something" dependency function without making it be recognized as a query parameter?

Rewrote Route Handler

Used default arguments but that's not how FastAPI's dependency injections works so no good

Maybe the use of lambda itself forces FastAPI to recognize it as a Query Parameter?

Tried setting a type for "request" as "Request" but then I get a syntax issue, tried wrapping it in parentheses and it still didn't work.

Asked ChatGPT for guidance



The signature of your lambda is just some random argument, request - how would FastAPI know what this argument should be? The default is that it's a query param if nothing else is given, and in this case, nothing else is actually given. If you want to recognize it as something else, type it appropriately.

@MatsLindh Forgot to mention in post that I tried doing that. I got a syntax issue.
Depends(lambda request: Request : do_something(request, "some-value"))

Yeah, you can't do that in a lambda. It's specifically excluded in the PEP that describes typing (as it would require changing the syntax for lambdas). So no, you can't do that with a lambda. Make an actual function instead. A common way to do this it to have your function return a closure instead (i.e. another internal function), then use Depends(my_function("some-value")) and have my_function return a function with proper typing (and the some-value value will be bound to the inner function, so it doesn't need to be part of the arguments to that function).

My current solution to this is the following
def get_do_something(value: str):
    async def fixed_do_something(request: Request):
        return await do_something(request, roles)
    return fixed_do_something

Notice how instead of directly passing the request with your additional parameters, you're now using a nested function. This nested function handles the additional requirements. Following this convention simplifies development and makes the process more efficient.
@some_router.post("/some-route") 
async def handleRoute(something = Depends(get_do_something('some-value'))):     
    return JSONResponse(content = {"msg": "Route"}, status_code = 200)

